# The bootstrap form isn't responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a login form in bootstrap.I think the code in html and css is Ok. The only problem is that this form isn't responsive eventhough I have introdused the rows and columns of bootstrap to make it responsive.

**Code:**

```css
.contain {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 1000px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  border-radius: none;
  width: 1050px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<div class=" contain">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body panelo">
        <div class="client"><b>SEI GIÀ CLIENTE? ACCEDI </b>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-6 labelField">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-4 labelField">
                  <strong><br>EMAIL</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8  col-sm-8">
                  <input class="ut" type="mail">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 labelField">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 labelField">
                  <strong><br>PASSWORD</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                  <input class="ut" type="mail">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 pass "><a href="#"> Hai dimenticato la password?</a> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <img src="images/entra.png" class=" registrati img-responsive">

        <img src="images/fb.png" class="registrati img-responsive">

        <div class="divider">
        </div>
        <div class="client"><b>NON ANCORA CLIENTE? </b>
        </div>
        <div class="benvenuto "><b>  BENVENUTO!  </b>
          <a href="registration.html">
            <img class="add1" src="images/Capture.png" class="img-responsive"><span class="creare"> Crea il tuo account su motogm e prosegue con il tuo ordine</span>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Is there something I should change to make this responsive?
Thanks!

Comment: Check your spelling. You have class=" contain", it should be class="container"

Comment: @nmg49 if that is the cause then this question is a simple typographical error on the part of the user and should be closed.

Comment: @Martin nope that doesnt change anything for sure. I have tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a lot of things that are missing right here:

First, the html it is bad structured it doesn't contain any body tag and you aren't closing the head tag. You didn't include the bootstrap.css either and it won't work that way...

As someone pointed out you should be using either `container` or `container-fluid`, instead of your custom class `contain`. And as suggestion, you shouldn't set fixed widths to your classes, because bootstrap works with percentages width.

This is a working snippet which is responsive. I removed some parts of your html to make the code more clear.

```html
<html><head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body style="
    /* width: 100%; */
">
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset></form></div>
        
    



</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change   div class=" contain" to   div class="container", this should be the first thing to test :)

Comment: Nope nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

In your head tag you need to add a meta tag

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Without the viewport set none of your responsive css will be run.

You also seem to have your divs inside a head tag. Divs should be inside the body tag.

Comment: Yes I have those tags but I removed them because my demo would be too long.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to dive deeply in documentation

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

I think you looking for some from bootstrap classes say `.form-control .form-group` ..etc

Also there is no class="contain" class instead use  `class="container"` or `class="container-fluid"`